# Using a different Search API for Shopify storefront

Tags: javascript, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-app

Am working on a code to power the Search with some external API in my Shopify storefront. I want to inject [Bloomreach Product Search API](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/search-and-merchandising/docs/milestone-4.-api-deployment/search-and-merchandising-feature-apis/product-search-api/product-search-api.html) in my existing Shopify storefront and provide product search operations.
Am not really sure how to achieve this? The scenario is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751259/write-custom-search-app-in-shopify) but am finding it hard to convert to a solution. May be because am new to Shopify don't exactly know how to make this work.

Can someone share some approach? Thanks.

Comment: This is too big of a project to provide any guidance here. You need to pull all the store data, create custom Rest API/GraphQL and query your database, in addition there must be an auto-sync option. The question is too vague to provide a specific answer here.

Comment: @drip I know it's something big, but even outlining an approach would also be good for the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the next steps:
1) Create template, that will return search result in json. Example: collection.data-json.liquid

```
{% layout none %}{% capture output %}[
{% paginate collection.products by 1000 %}
{% for product in collection.products %}
{
"id":{{product.id}},
"available":{{product.available}},
"handle":"{{product.handle}}",
"title":{{product.title | json}},
"price":{{product.price_min}},
}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
]{% endcapture %}{{ output | strip_newlines }}
```

2) Make an ajax request to getting required data according to query search:

fetch('/collections?view=data-json&title=test&id=123').then(...);

You can try to filter products with this approach.

Comment: I want to empower search using third party search API from Shopify storefront, this is not exactly what I intend to do.